# Receiving error: "200": "parsererror": SyntaxError: "Unexpected end of input" during jquery ajax call

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "MyServlet",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        type: "post",
        cache: false
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert('hello');
    }).fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error: ' + XMLHttpRequest.status + ": " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ": " + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
    });
```

And I receive: "error: 200: parsererror: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

I can't figure out why.  Any help?

My servlet is basically returning the following:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("test", "hello servlet");
out.print(json);
out.close();
```

Comment: First thing to do: check if you can access the same data directly through a web browser, and make sure its syntax is correct.

Comment: It seems that returned data is not JSON.

Comment: need more info. your should post the `responseText` here.

Comment: I added my servlet code above.  It is pretty straightforward.

Comment: The response text is simply returning: 200

Comment: Blazemonger: How would I go about accessing 'the same data directly through a web browser'?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured this out.  I was not closing the out stream in my servlet properly which resulted in bad json data being returned.